# npm update error while trying to install ionic

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, ionic-framework

I've got problems trying to install NPM.
Always worked well, but now, i've to install "ionic" and the problem is that when i tried to re-install nodejs all work well, it seems that npm installed but trying to update it, it gives me errors, so i tried to update it via this command:

```
 curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

I cannot install ionic, i don't know why. I've installed months ago cordova and phonegap, but ionic gives me trouble. 
Reading guides, tell me to update my npm and doing this, that what i've (this is the following error using the command above)

```
    cleanup prefix=/usr/local

All clean!
unbuild npm@1.4.14
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.2.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/private/var/folders/ry/gd7h2rhs52n10yr83_w50wyw0000gp/T/npm.18934/package/cli.js" "rm" "npm" "-gf"
npm ERR! cwd /private/var/folders/ry/gd7h2rhs52n10yr83_w50wyw0000gp/T/npm.18934/package
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.16
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /private/var/folders/ry/gd7h2rhs52n10yr83_w50wyw0000gp/T/npm.18934/package/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

> npm@1.4.16 prepublish .
> node bin/npm-cli.js prune --prefix=. --no-global && rm -rf test/*/*/node_modules && make -j32 doc

make: Nothing to be done for `doc'.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR! error rolling back  npm@1.4.16 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' }
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.2.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/private/var/folders/ry/gd7h2rhs52n10yr83_w50wyw0000gp/T/npm.18934/package/cli.js" "install" "-gf"
npm ERR! cwd /private/var/folders/ry/gd7h2rhs52n10yr83_w50wyw0000gp/T/npm.18934/package
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.16
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /private/var/folders/ry/gd7h2rhs52n10yr83_w50wyw0000gp/T/npm.18934/package/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: From the pastebin of the error you posted, it cannot unlink the version of node find: /usr/local/lib/node: No such file or directory. Try running `sudo unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm` manually and then rerun the script, this may alleviate the error npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'on line 18.

Comment: `unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
unlink: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm: is a directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using the command `sudo su` on my mac os x (so without using sudo with the commando or sudo $username).
then using the curl commando it run.

Thanks however.
**Might this answer could be usefull**

Comment: Yes worked for me on a mac using:
`sudo npm install -g cordova ionic`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm

   sudo curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```